# Is there a way to set app compatibility per android version (not API level) in the play store?

Tags: android, version, google-play

I have an app that works on Android 2.3.6, but will cause [disruptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804304/when-does-android-show-a-pairing-dialog-when-using-insecure-rfcomm-bluetooth-soc) if deployed on 2.3.3. I will obviously implement some mechanism to stop it from working on such devices, but is there a way to mark an app compatible with 2.3.6 but incompatible with 2.3.3, so the play store and possibly package installer would detect the incompatibilty? (Both versions are API level 10, otherwise this would be easy.)

Comment: you can manually select devices that you dont want support

Comment: @vincent: I know, however, that will be of little use, since e.g. a Galaxy Ace can have either 2.3.3 or 2.3.6.

Answer (score 0):

check (String androidOS = Build.VERSION.RELEASE) while starting , then close or take action manually. As far as i know , i think if api levels are same , you cant do it via manifest